# How to solve recurrence relation by iteration

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations

How exactly are those solved? Would appreciate an explenation as I cannot find a good one.

$$
\begin{cases}
T(1)= 1 \\
f(n) = \log_2(n)\\
T(n) = a\, T(n-1) + f(n)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Who is $T(2)$? And $T(3)$? Can you find a general rule?

Comment: @SewerKeeper I know that I must go like ```T(n) = a*T(n-1)+log2n = a*a*T(n-2) + log2n-1...``` but I am not quite sure if its right and how to do from there. I managed to do some easier examples but this one is hard for me.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 1):

Well let's try
$$T(n)=aT(n-1)+\log_2(n)$$
$$T(n-1)=aT(n-2)+\log_2(n-1)$$
So 
$$T(n)=a(aT(n-2)+\log_2(n-1))+\log_2(n)$$
$$=a^2T(n-2)+\log_2(n(n-1)^a)$$
$$=a^2(aT(n-3)+\log_2(n-2))+\log_2(n(n-1)^a)$$
$$=a^3T(n-3)+\log_2(n(n-1)^a(n-2)^{a^2})$$
So we can conjecture (and the proof by induction is left as an exercise)
$$T(n)=a^kT(n-k)+\log_2(n(n-1)^a(n-2)^{a^2}\dots(n-(k-1))^{a^{k-1}})$$
So putting $k=n-1$, we get
$$T(n)=a^{n-1}T(1)+\log_2(n(n-1)^a(n-2)^{a^2}\dots(2)^{a^{n-2}})$$
$$=a^{n-1}+\log_2(n(n-1)^a(n-2)^{a^2}\dots(2)^{a^{n-2}})$$
for all $n \ge 2$.

Note: trying $T(2)=a+1$ and then $T(3)=a(a+1)+\log_2(3)=a^2+a+\log_2(3)$ and we can substitute in the formula to find that it works: 
$$T(3)=a^2 + \log_2(3 \cdot 2^a)=a^2+a+\log_2(3)$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So the big O notation would be O(log n)? I am not quite sure with that complex problems.

Comment: @Sowik what big O notation?

Comment: The complexity of the algorithm

Comment: @Sowik sorry but I don't get it, what I did was try to iterate and then find a pattern, get a conjecture, prove it by induction, and then get a formula

Comment: @Sowik I searched for the big O notation, and I think it would be $O(3^{n-2})$ or something, but try to do it yourself and prove it.
I'm not particularly experienced in this field and I think you're obviously studying Computer Science stuff, so it should be yours to try and solve, not ours.
Furthermore, you should've introduced that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$T(n)=f(n)+aT(n-1)=f(n) + a( f(n-1)+ a T(n-2))=$$
$$=f(n)+af(n-1)+a^2T(n-2)=$$
$$= f(n)+af(n-1)+a^2f(n-2)+ a^3T(n-3)=\cdots$$

Can you guess a formula? Once you have your guess, try to prove it is correct verifying it satisfies the relevant recursive relation.

Spoiler:

> \begin{align} T(n)= f(n) +af(n-1) + \cdots + a^{n-2}f(2)+ a^{n-1}T(1) = a^{n-1} + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \log_2(k) a^{n-k} \end{align}

Comment: And once we get a formula how do we find the complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: I added a spoiler with the formula. What algorithm? You mean an algorithm to compute the formula, or is it like the formula pops up as the computational complexity (number of elementary operations) of some algorithm given an input of size $n$? In the latter case I guess you may want to have an asymptotic estimate of the formula as $n \to \infty$. Such an estimate depends on whether $a>1$ or not.

Comment: Big O Notation for the algorithm. Also thank you for taking out of your time to explain this to me.

Comment: If $0<a<1$ then $T(n) =O(\log(n))$;
if $a=1$ then $T(n)=O(n\log(n))$;
if $a>1$ then $T(n)=O(a^n)$